# Natbib: How to use authoryear style in-text and numbering in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am now writing a project paper which has several citations. My tutor requests me to use(Author, Year) style in text for reference purposes, but the bibliography need to have numbering. How do I achieve a hybrid of both style in natbib package?
Thanks!

Comment: Why with natbib? Won't be easier to achieve that with bibilatex?

Comment: Any chance you can convince your tutor that his/her requirement is a bad idea, typographically speaking? When using author-year citation callouts, prefixing the entries in the bibliography with numbers is utterly pointless. All the numbers provide in such a case is visual clutter.

Comment: @Aradnix - Just because *might* be done with some tool doesn't mean that it *should* be done, right?

Comment: @Mico Right, that's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when you redefine `biblabel` to add labels in the reference list, that'll automatically show the number as a label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\NAT@biblabel[1]{[#1]} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Text \cite{ref}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```