# Natbib: Author-year in the text but numbered bibliography

Tags: natbib

I would like to keep the standard natbib author-year citations within my main text, e.g. (Allan et al. 2009), but also have numbering in my bibliograpy/reference list, e.g.

1. Allan, B.F., Langerhans and R.B., Ryberg (2009). Ecological correlates of risk and incidence of West Nile virus in the United States. Oncologia, 158, 699–708.

Is this possible? [I know it may not be optimal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205400/natbib-how-to-use-authoryear-style-in-text-and-numbering-in-the-bibliography) but that is not my choice.

Comment: It is easy to do with `biblatex`, which has a `natbib emulation` mode: it's enough to load biblatex with option: `citationstyle=authoryear` ot one of its variants. For the bibliography, `numeric` is the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply constructing a working example from [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228914/natbib-author-year-in-the-text-but-numbered-bibliography#comment540278_228914) above (@Bernard, feel free to take my answer and repost it).

[image: All thanks to]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{veblen1919place,
  title={The Place of Science in Modern Civilisation: and other essays},
  author={Veblen, Thorstein},
  year={1919},
  publisher={BW Huebsch}
}
@book{veblen2007theory,
  title={The theory of the leisure class},
  author={Veblen, Thorstein},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
 url = {http://www.test.org}
}
@book{knuth1989texbook,
  title={The TEXbook},
  author={Knuth, D.E.},
  series={Computers \& and typesetting},
  url={https://books.google.com/books?id=kURPnQEACAAJ},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Addison Wesley}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric, natbib=true, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
As \citeauthor*{veblen2007theory} has argued \citep[12--19]{veblen1919place} it is clear that $y$. Second,  \citet[12]{veblen1919place} also show $m$ and $x$ \citet[37]{veblen1919place}. All thanks to \citeauthor*{ knuth1989texbook}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```