# Numbered Author-year ACM Refrences Style

Tags: bibliographies, acm

It is told to use `ACM-Reference-Format` for the paper `bibliography` style. I used [ACM-Reference-Format.bst](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/acmart/ACM-Reference-Format.bst). However, `ACM-Reference-Format` is not numbered, but it is needed to be numbered in my paper. 
I saw the [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228914/natbib-author-year-in-the-text-but-numbered-bibliography) and used `biblatex` package, but that does not work for me.
What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used ‎`\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}‎` for package

and ‎`\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}‎` for style and it solved my problem.